# How do on kill sigils work together?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I have a Superior Sigil of Life (gain a charge of +10 healing everytime you kill a foe (max 25)) in my main hand and a Major Sigil of Restoration (gain health on killing a foe) in my offhand.
I assumed they should perfectly work together as the off hand sigil isn't stacking, yet they don't. I don't gain health on kill unless I change my main hand.

I am now confused as to how 'on kill' sigils work together as the wiki only mentions that you can only have 1 stack active. Is it normal that they don't work together or a bug?

Answer (score 1):

On-kill sigils have stacks of up to 25 (you'll see a buff that stacks up to 25) which reset when you die. You should get hp when you kill an enemy, as well, as there is no reason for these two particular sigils to not work together as they don't share the same internal cooldown (ICD).

Comment: That's what I thought but I don't get hp, hence my question..

Comment: According to [the wiki](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Sigil_of_Restoration) it might not work if you don't get XP from the kill?

Comment: I've read that too so I made sure to check I got xp from the kill.